# If $\log_2\sin(10^{\circ})=\alpha$, what is the value of $\log_2\left(\dfrac{\sin20^{\circ}+\sin40^{\circ}}{\sin20^\circ}\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

If $\log_2\sin(10^{\circ})=\alpha$, what is the value of $\log_2\left(\dfrac{\sin20^{\circ}+\sin40^{\circ}}{\sin20^\circ}\right)$?

$1)-1-\alpha\qquad\qquad2)-1+\alpha\qquad\qquad3)1-\alpha\qquad\qquad4)1+\alpha$

Here is what I did:

$$\log_2\left(\dfrac{\sin20^{\circ}+\sin40^{\circ}}{\sin20^\circ}\right)=\log_2\left(1+\dfrac{\sin40^{\circ}}{\sin20^\circ}\right)=\log_2\left(1+2\cos20^{\circ}\right)=\log_2\left(3-4\sin^210^{\circ}\right)$$
But I can't continue from here, even using $\sin10^{\circ}=2^{\alpha}$ didn't help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\log_2\left(\dfrac{\sin20^{\circ}+\sin40^{\circ}}{\sin20^\circ}\right)$

$\log_2\left(\dfrac{2\sin30^{\circ}\cos 10^{\circ}}{\sin20^\circ}\right)$

$\log_2\left(\dfrac{\cos 10^{\circ}}{2\sin10^\circ\cos 10^{\circ}}\right)$

$\log_2\left(\dfrac{1}{2\sin10^\circ}\right)$

$-\log_2\left({2\sin10^\circ}\right)$

$-\log_2\left(2\right)-\log_2\left(\sin 10^\circ\right)$

$-1-\alpha$

Well, you are also very close to answer

$\log _2 (3-4\sin^2 10)$

$\log _2 \frac{3\sin10-4\sin^3 10}{\sin 10}$

$\log _2 \frac{\sin 30}{\sin 10}$

$\log _2 \frac{1}{2\sin 10}$

$-1-\alpha$

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{\sin20^\circ+\sin 40^\circ}{\sin20^\circ}=\frac{2\sin30^\circ\cos10^\circ}{2\sin10^\circ\cos10^\circ}=\frac1{2\sin10^\circ}$.

Comment: Wonderful approach really to solve this question/ +1